# Create multiple conditional row and add specific values from another dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

Good afternoon,

I am trying to add new rows on a dataframe where I have data for many sources. What I am trying to do is add a new row at the start of a source and replace column values with specific values from another table.

To give you an example, suppose I have a dataframe which gives certain information for each Source (referred as Stack) as shown in the figure below:

[image]

And I have the following input file: 
[image]

I am trying to create a new row at the start of each source and add the relevant information from the information table (the first figure) so that the result look like this:

[image]

I know how to add a new row at the start of a dataframe for example similar to this:

```
v1=c(1,2,3)
v2= c(7,8,9)
dat= data.frame(v1,v2)
new_dat <- rbind(c(0,10000), dat)
```

but not sure how to condition this to add row at specific position with the information from figure 1.

I have many sources and very large dataset but to give some reproducible data as shown in the 2 tables, please see below the input tables that I am testing with:

The information table(first figure):

```
> dput(stack_info)
structure(list(SNAME = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"
), class = "factor"), ISVARY = c(1L, 4L), VELVOL = c(1L, 4L), 
    TEMPDENS = c(0L, 2L), `DUM 1` = c(999L, 999L), `DUM 2` = c(999L, 
    999L), NPOL = c(2L, 2L), `EXIT VEL` = c(26.2, 22.4), TEMP = c(341L, 
    328L), `STACK DIAM` = c(1.5, 2.5), W = c(0L, 15L), Nox = c(39, 
    33.3), Sox = c(15.5, 17.9)), .Names = c("SNAME", "ISVARY", 
"VELVOL", "TEMPDENS", "DUM 1", "DUM 2", "NPOL", "EXIT VEL", "TEMP", 
"STACK DIAM", "W", "Nox", "Sox"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

the input table that I am working with (second figure):

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(Source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L), day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), `EXIT VEL` = c(26.2, 
    26.2, 26.2, 26.2, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4), TEMP = c(341L, 
    341L, 341L, 341L, 328L, 328L, 328L, 328L, 328L), `STACK DIAM` = c(1.5, 
    1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), W = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), Nox = c(39, 39, 39, 39, 33.3, 
    33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3), Sox = c(15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 
    17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9)), .Names = c("Source", "year", 
"day", "hour", "EXIT VEL", "TEMP", "STACK DIAM", "W", "Nox", 
"Sox"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I would be grateful if I could get any guidance on how to add conditional row with values from a different dataframe

thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to add a row of column names? Is that it? If so, that's a very bad idea. Either keep the data the way it is or split it into multiple dataframes.

Comment: Hi @Molx, It is kind of column names but need to go at the start of each source based on the source information. It is just the way the template I need to create which is very unusual in terms of data structure wise and each source will be stacked with this unusual style of headers that then I need to convert to a text file to read into a model.

Comment: Then it's probably best to split them into separate dataframes, give each one its appropriate header and then write to file using `append = TRUE`. I guess it should work.

Comment: thanks @Molx, I managed to split data in a list with this: `out <- split( test2 , f = test2$Source)`, but struggling with extract colnames from the info dataset and assigning to new tables. Do you have any recommendation to how I can do this in a loop and add back to a single dataframe as shown in the example desired output figure? I may be totally wrong thinking that this need to be in a loop? thanks in advance

Comment: this is now resolved as with the help of @Tensibai I have managed to create a code suitable for my original datasets which is now working, see question -  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616966/r-changing-colnames-with-a-loop-with-names-from-another-table/32630854?noredirect=1#comment53113938_32630854)