# R - Changing colnames with a loop with names from another table

Tags: r

I am trying to split a large dataset and

1. assign colnames with a loop and
2. save all individual data back again in a single stacked file

I am using some sample data as follows:

[image]

so firstly I split the datasets into 2 based on number of sources in the first column and read in a list using the following code:

```
out <- split( sample , f = sample$Source)
```

now I am struggling to set up a loop to change the colnames for coloumn 2 to 8 
by matching the existing colnames to the following 'info' table and replacing based on source name as in the first column of the 'info' table.

the info table looks like this:

[image]

so the loop should change the colnames similar to this: 
[image]

I am just wondering if anyone has done something similar could advise me?

also when I try to join them together I can only set the colnames ones using the merge function. is there any way to stack them so that I can preserve the colname for each table and looks something like this? :

[image]

my sample input files are:

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(Source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L), day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), `EXIT VEL` = c(26.2, 
    26.2, 26.2, 26.2, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4, 22.4), TEMP = c(341L, 
    341L, 341L, 341L, 328L, 328L, 328L, 328L, 328L), `STACK DIAM` = c(1.5, 
    1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), W = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), Nox = c(39, 39, 39, 39, 33.3, 
    33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3), Sox = c(15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 
    17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9)), .Names = c("Source", "year", 
"day", "hour", "EXIT VEL", "TEMP", "STACK DIAM", "W", "Nox", 
"Sox"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

> dput(stack_info)
structure(list(SNAME = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Stack 1", "Stack 2"
), class = "factor"), ISVARY = c(1L, 4L), VELVOL = c(1L, 4L), 
    TEMPDENS = c(0L, 2L), `DUM 1` = c(999L, 999L), `DUM 2` = c(999L, 
    999L), NPOL = c(2L, 2L), `EXIT VEL` = c(26.2, 22.4), TEMP = c(341L, 
    328L), `STACK DIAM` = c(1.5, 2.5), W = c(0L, 15L), Nox = c(39, 
    33.3), Sox = c(15.5, 17.9)), .Names = c("SNAME", "ISVARY", 
"VELVOL", "TEMPDENS", "DUM 1", "DUM 2", "NPOL", "EXIT VEL", "TEMP", 
"STACK DIAM", "W", "Nox", "Sox"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do this? R ≠ Excel

Comment: Hi @ Jaap, this is only a little sample I have number of files with large amount of data and excel just too slow to even load them. the example I am trying its only to test and then I will write something to fit my original datasets. thanks

Comment: But what's wrong with the current state? And where do the values in red come from?

Comment: @Jaap,  the current state is the figure 1. what I need to do is ultimately set up a template just like my last figure. the values for the red coming from the figure 2 which is the "stack_info" table dput() I have provided. I have been advised to split the input data (figure 1 - values are provided in the dput(sample)) and for each source (the left column) and assign colname and save back as a stacked file as last figure

Comment: As an aside, column names with only numbers and duplicate column names are not practical in R.

Comment: I think that what @Jaap mean is that you can't have multiples headers in a data frame. but your actual `out` content is a list, so What is your actual problem ? writing this list in a file with headers changed at each list item ?

Comment: Hi @Tensibai, yes this is what exactly I am trying to do. writing the tables from that list with changed header to a single dataframe preserving the header for each table in the stacked single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I ended with is this:

```
out <- split( sample , f = sample$Source) # your original step

stack_info[,1] <- as.character(stack_info[,1]) # To get strings column as strings and not index number later
out <- lapply( names(out), function(x) {
                      # Get the future names
                      new_cnames <- unname(unlist(stack_info[stack_info$SNAME == x,1:7]))
                      # replace the column names
                      colnames(out[[x]]) <- c("Source",new_cnames,colnames(out[[x]])[9:10] )
                      # Return the modified version without first column
                      out[[x]][,-1]  })

sapply(out,write.table,append=T,file="",row.names=F,sep="|") # write (change "" to the file name you wish and sep to your desired separator and see ?write.table for more documentation)
```

The main idea is looping over the DF to change their colnames, I do update the list and loop again to write, you may want to append to file in the first loop.

I hope the comments are enough to get the code, tell me if it needs some details.

Output on screen (omitting warnings):

```
 "Stack 1"|"1"|"1.1"|"0"|"999"|"999.1"|"2"|"Nox"|"Sox"
2010|1|0|26.2|341|1.5|0|39|15.5
2010|1|1|26.2|341|1.5|0|39|15.5
2010|1|2|26.2|341|1.5|0|39|15.5
2010|1|3|26.2|341|1.5|0|39|15.5
"Stack 2"|"4"|"4.1"|"2"|"999"|"999.1"|"2.1"|"Nox"|"Sox"
2010|1|0|22.4|328|2.5|15|33.3|17.9
2010|1|1|22.4|328|2.5|15|33.3|17.9
2010|1|2|22.4|328|2.5|15|33.3|17.9
2010|1|3|22.4|328|2.5|15|33.3|17.9
2010|1|4|22.4|328|2.5|15|33.3|17.9
```

Comment: hi @Tensibai, this is perfect and the lapply loop what I was after to get my head round. It gived me good idea and I can build up from this one. many thanks for your example!

Comment: hi @Tensibai, just wondering if there is any way I could write the headers without the '.1' at the end for some of the header or a way to get read of them from each header? thanks

Comment: @Achak I know no way for this, data frames can't have duplicate column names (or you won't be able to access one specifically). The answer is more in why you wish to put numbers in the column names at first

Comment: Ahh you are right we can't put duplicate on header. I will just do a post sort out in excel of the final templates. its a nightmare job to do this templates for this modelling software that I am using as it requires in this exact type of format but much larger files for number of years for multiple sources for every hour. Thank you so much as I am almost there now with what the final template should look like :)